# CacheStoreAdapter read-through does not add loaded items to memory cache

Tags: ignite

When the method

```
public Datom load(String key) throws CacheLoaderException
```

is executed in my implementation of CacheStoreAdapter, the data that I load from the underlying DB is not automatically added to the Ignite memory cache.  Is that by design?  Do I need to give a reference to the cache to my CacheStoreAdapter so that it can manually perform a `put()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be related to my eviction policy memory limit, which was set to 125 bytes instead of 125 mybtes...